# Dynamic AddressOf

Tags: vb.net, delegates

What is the best way of referencing a dynamic delegate. I'd like to do the following with method names returned from a configuration database.

```
AddressOf "MethodName"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via Reflection (specifically [Type.GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Use the classes in the System.Reflection namespace.

Answer (score 0):

AddressOf doesn't work that way, but you can use reflection to get a delegate for a method if you also know the assembly/class for the method.